# Appveyor uploading web deploy artifact

Tags: appveyor

I'm having some troubles setting up appveyor. I'd like to publish the generated web deploy packages to the Appveyor artifact feed. I've selected to build web deploy packages in appveyor.yml:

    `build:
      project: Apps/MyProject.sln
      publish_wap: true`

I can see from the logs that the 2 webdeploy packages get produced:

`[00:00:24]   Package "Backend.zip" is successfully created as single file at the following location:
[00:00:24]   file:///C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/cul57h0ak9`

I can push these packages to github releases by simply referring to them by filename:

`deploy:
- provider: GitHub
  tag: v$(appveyor_build_version)
  auth_token:
    secure: stuff
  artifact: api.zip, backend.zip
  force_update: false
  on:
    DEPLOY: true`

However, I'm unable to publish these packages to Appveyor artifact feed, because unlike "deployments", it seems that I'm required to know the exact path of the artifact(s). Appveyour seems to use a temp folder when it generates these, so it's pretty hopeless to know the path. I cold traverse the build agent's user's temp file directory looking for them, but that seems a bit hacky to me.

So, my question is: How do I reliably tell appveyor to send my generated zips to the artifact feed?

(Note that I know that I can configure a "publish target" in visual studio and use that instead, but as far as I can understand the whole idea behind the "publish_wap" option is to not have to do that for every project. I'm trying to achieve a clear separation of code so that no build-specific config has to be included inside my msbuild projects).

Comment: Could you please clarify, what you mean by "Appveyor artifact feed"? Your webdeploy packages by default will be available with those  links https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#permalink-to-the-last-successful-build-artifact and in "Artifacts" tab in UI.

Comment: I am so stupid. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Appveoyr auto-posts any artifacts, and now I feel stupid.